# Deploying scala app as a docker container

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, sbt-assembly

I'm trying to deploy this awesome Scala app as a Docker container.
https://github.com/OlegIlyenko/graphql-toolbox

It uses an sbt build system. I tried running sbt in a container, using this Dockerfile.
https://gist.github.com/rzachariah/77eb927f650347ef06d0009dc220cd4a

The container builds and starts, but then exits immediately.

I guess `sbt run` is an interactive process--not a daemonized process. Probably a bad idea to `sbt run` in a container.

I started looking into sbt-assembly to create a fat jar that I could just execute.
https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

I get some errors when I do `sbt assembly`.

`C:\Users\rzachariah\.ivy2\cache\commons-logging\commons-logging\jars\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SimpleLog.class
        at sbtassembly.Assembly$.applyStrategies(Assembly.scala:140)
        at sbtassembly.Assembly$.x$1$lzycompute$1(Assembly.scala:25)
        at sbtassembly.Assembly$.x$1$1(Assembly.scala:23)
        at sbtassembly.Assembly$.stratMapping$lzycompute$1(Assembly.scala:23)
        at sbtassembly.Assembly$.stratMapping$1(Assembly.scala:23)
        at sbtassembly.Assembly$.inputs$lzycompute$1(Assembly.scala:67)
        at sbtassembly.Assembly$.inputs$1(Assembly.scala:57)
        at sbtassembly.Assembly$.apply(Assembly.scala:83)
        at sbtassembly.Assembly$$anonfun$assemblyTask$1.apply(Assembly.scala:240)
        at sbtassembly.Assembly$$anonfun$assemblyTask$1.apply(Assembly.scala:237)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[error] (*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] C:\Users\rzachariah\.ivy2\cache\io.netty\netty-handler\jars\netty-handler-4.0.36.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
[error] C:\Users\rzachariah\.ivy2\cache\io.netty\netty-buffer\jars\netty-buffer-4.0.36.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
[error] C:\Users\rzachariah\.ivy2\cache\io.netty\netty-common\jars\netty-common-4.0.36.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
[error] C:\Users\rzachariah\.ivy2\cache\io.netty\netty-transport\jars\netty-transport-4.0.36.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
[error] C:\Users\rzachariah\.ivy2\cache\io.netty\netty-codec\jars\netty-codec-4.0.36.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
[error] C:\Users\rzachariah\.ivy2\cache\io.netty\netty-codec-http\jars\netty-codec-http-4.0.36.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
[error] C:\Users\rzachariah\.ivy2\cache\io.netty\netty-transport-native-epoll\jars\netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.36.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] C:\Users\rzachariah\.ivy2\cache\org.slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\jars\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.19.jar:org/apache/commons/logging/Log.class
[error] C:\Users\rzachariah\.ivy2\cache\commons-logging\commons-logging\jars\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:org/apache/commons/logging/Log.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] C:\Users\rzachariah\.ivy2\cache\org.slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\jars\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.19.jar:org/apache/commons/logging/LogConfigurationException.class
[error] C:\Users\rzachariah\.ivy2\cache\commons-logging\commons-logging\jars\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:org/apache/commons/logging/LogConfigurationException.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] C:\Users\rzachariah\.ivy2\cache\org.slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\jars\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.19.jar:org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory.class
[error] C:\Users\rzachariah\.ivy2\cache\commons-logging\commons-logging\jars\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] C:\Users\rzachariah\.ivy2\cache\org.slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\jars\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.19.jar:org/apache/commons/logging/impl/NoOpLog.class
[error] C:\Users\rzachariah\.ivy2\cache\commons-logging\commons-logging\jars\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:org/apache/commons/logging/impl/NoOpLog.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] C:\Users\rzachariah\.ivy2\cache\org.slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\jars\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.19.jar:org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SimpleLog$1.class
[error] C:\Users\rzachariah\.ivy2\cache\commons-logging\commons-logging\jars\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SimpleLog$1.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] C:\Users\rzachariah\.ivy2\cache\org.slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\jars\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.19.jar:org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SimpleLog.class
[error] C:\Users\rzachariah\.ivy2\cache\commons-logging\commons-logging\jars\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SimpleLog.class
[error] Total time: 5 s, completed Oct 10, 2016 6:41:44 PM`

I think I need to define a merge strategy, but I'm a bit confused on how to do that. Any pointers? I am a total Scala newbie.

Comment: I believe it's really bad idea to run production app with sbt. I pack my apps with that plugin: http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/. Pack it and than just add that fat app into docker image

Comment: There are a lot of packaging options available here.
http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/

Is this a good packaging option?
https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

Any tips on how to add a merge strategy to a build that looks like this?
https://github.com/OlegIlyenko/graphql-toolbox/blob/master/build.sbt

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I learned that since my scala app uses the play framework, and the native packager is built in, packaging my app into a container is super easy!

```
sbt docker:publishLocal
```

http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html